# req body is always empty on post express js

Tags: express, post, body-parser

I am trying to get req.body on POST method using ExpressJS

But I can always get empty json object ({}).

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body) // {}
  res.send(200, req.body);  // {}
});
```

Who can help me?

I am using :
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",

Comment: FYI, `app.use(bodyParse.json());` is misspelled and should be `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed 'content-type' as 'X-www-form-url-encoded' on Postman.
And then i can show the correct body. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What does your submit form look like? You need to make sure a POST request hits the "/" route.

You can try manually with Postman to see if it goes through.

Comment: I tried to test with Postman. But I can't get the result.

Comment: Make sure you are sending the request as json, that is what it expects.